# What is the exact definition of a Weight balanced tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

There are many definitions given for a weight balanced tree. I got confused which one to follow and it is difficult to understand the definitions given.

> A node is balanced if weight[n.left] ≥ weight[n] and weight[n.right] ≥
>   weight[n]
>
> Number of nodes in the left and right sub tree must be equal
>
> A weight-balanced tree is a binary tree in which for each node, the
>   number of nodes in the left sub tree is at least half and at most
>   twice the number of nodes in the right sub tree.

Can somebody explain me which is the correct one?

Comment: What is the problem with these definitions?  I believe that the motivation for constructing a weight balanced tree is that it guarantees a certain performance in, for example, a sorting algorithm.

Comment: What is the advantage of a weight balanced tree over a height balanced tree?

Comment: can you give me the correct and exact definition of a weight balanced tree? with a proof

Comment: You cannot give definitions with proofs, that is contradictory. A definition doesn't need to be proven

Comment: okay. just give me a definition for a weight balanced tree with an explanation

Comment: That statement is wrong: `Number of nodes in the left and right sub tree must be equal`, that might be true for rotated wbt. The first statement you copied from wiki, and I just don't understand what they say, it doesn't make sense. The third statement is just an observation, since it is a binary tree, so ofc you won't habe larger factors of nodes in one than in the other subnode.

Comment: @RobertStettler Thank you. But still, I don't get it. Can you explain the third one or just give me an easy definition of a wbt?

Comment: @RobertStettler And, how did you say _Number of nodes in the left and right sub tree must be equal_ is wrong?. That's the definition I have seen in many places.

Comment: Think of the purpose it serves: to find an "arbitrary" node, it's optimal if the depth is minimal to minimize average travel. A little thinking will convince you that this implies that there should ideally be an equal number of nodes right and left and, importantly, that this holds at every level and at every node. When adding nodes it is impractical to enforce this equality strictly - you would have to rebalance too often, so "rule of thumb": rebalance when ratio left/right <0.5 or >2. "Weight" in weight-balanced is simply the number of nodes: left and right should have equal weights.

Comment: @BertteVelde   So if the **Number of nodes in the left and right sub tree is equal**, it is a weight balanced tree. Correct?. But what does the statement given in the answer imply?

Comment: All definitions are "correct", there is no "the" definition. You define it as is convenient for your particular application.

Comment: Yes, weight-balanced means equals numbers right/left, but for practical reasons we "allow" some inbalance (ratio's >0.5 <2, but you could also use other "thresholds") in order not to REbalance with each and every "addNode", and of course because you simply cannot always have perfect balance: that would require that the total nr = (2^p)-1 for some p. For explanation of formula's in other answers I suggest you ask their authors. You may also consult general info, for instance wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight-balanced_tree

Comment: WRONG. The definition in 'Advanced Data Structures' by Peter Brass (PDF downloadable [here](http://www.proklondike.com/books/dbobshee/Advanced_Data_Structures.html)), which is claimed a source for the Wikipedia's statement, differs from what you cite above in one word, but the meaning is totally different: *'The **weight of a tree** is the number of its **leaves** (...).'* (page 62). Additionally it says *'The node `*n` is α-weight-balanced if
`n->left->weight ≥ α n->weight` and `n->right->weight ≥ α n->weight`'* (page 63). Wikipedia lost the 'alpha' factor, which made the statement absurd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I learnt it, the balance `p()` of a node `n` in a wbt is given by

```
p(n) = s(n.l)/s(n) = 1 - s(n.r)/s(n)
```

where `s` is the number of descendant leaves. You can now start to rebalance the tree by using rotation and double-rotation operations. Now, if you have a even number of leaves, then the statement is true that for each node, the number of subnodes in the left and in the right node is equal. That holds only for balanced wbt. That is not always possible, if you have 6 leaves, how do you balance that so that that statement holds?

Rebalancing reduces the height of a wbt.

Example: you have a wbt with one million leaves in the left node and a couple ones in the right node. You can now start to rotate the leaves so that the number of leaves in the left sub tree is

> at least half and at most twice the number of nodes in the right sub tree

One statement is:

> The tree is of **bounded balance** *a* if for every node

```
a <= p(n) <= 1-a
```

Comment: Can you explain the statement? What is p(n)?

Comment: What statement? p is the balance of a node.

Comment: So what should be the optimal value of p(n)? or What will be the value of p(n) for the root of a wbt?

Comment: I changed the answer, may that helps